# How do I convert matrices from Matlab to Python?

Tags: python, matlab, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have the following code in Matlab which I'm not familiar with:

```matlab
function segments = segmentEnergy(data, th)
    mag = sqrt(sum(data(:, 1:3) .^ 2, 2));
    mag = mag - mean(mag);

    above = find(mag>=th*std(mag));
    indicator = zeros(size(mag));
    indicator(above) = 1;
    plot(mag); hold on; plot(indicator*1000, 'r')
end
```

I wrote this following function in Python:

```py
def segment_energy(data, th):
    mag = np.linalg.norm((data['x'], data['y'], data['z']))
    print "This is the mag: " + str(mag)
    mag -= np.mean(mag)

    above = np.where(mag >= th * np.std(mag))
    indicator = np.zeros(mag.shape)
    indicator[above] = 1
    plt.plot(mag)
    plt.plot(indicator * 1000, 'r')
    plt.show()
```

I get an error:

```py
line 23, in segment_energy
indicator[above] = 1
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

`data` is a pandas `DataFrame` that was read from a CSV file containing triaxial accelerometer data. The axes of the accelerometer data are `x`, `y`, and `z`. The columns for the data frame are `timestamp`, `time skipped`, `x`, `y`, `z`, and `label` in that order.

The error is because `mag` in the Python code is a scalar and I'm treating it like a matrix. However, I'm not sure how they're turning `mag` into a matrix in the MATLAB function.

Comment: What is `data`?

Comment: `data` is a data frame from a CSV file.

Comment: Then try using `mag = np.linalg.norm(data.iloc[:,1:3].values())`

Comment: The indices of `data` for `x`, `y`, and `z` are 2, 3, and 4 respectively.

Comment: Um, ok. I can only assume `data` is some sort of matrix, and `data(:, 1:3)` in matlab takes all the rows, and columns 1-3. There might be subtlties involved in the inclusiveness or exclusiveness of the endpoints...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `numpy.linalg.norm` by default would give you a single scalar value given how you are currently calling the function.   Because the output of `mag` is now a scalar, the rest of the code will not function as intended for the following reasons:

1. Performing mean subtraction with a single scalar will give you a value of 0 (i.e. `mag <- mag - np.mean(mag) --> 0`).
2. The `above` statement will always return a tuple of a single element.  This element contains a NumPy array of length 1 containing the index 0, symbolizing that the first element of the "array" which is a scalar in this case satisfies the constraint.  This is satisfied always as the standard deviation of a single constant is also 0 by using the default definition of `np.std`.
3. Calling `shape` for a single scalar value is undefined and it will actually give you an empty shape: `()`.  Note that if you did not subtract with `numpy.mean`, doing `mag.shape` would actually give you an error as it is not a NumPy array.  Subtracting with `np.mean` coalesces the scalar to a NumPy array.

   Observe:

   ```
   In [56]: mag = 10

   In [57]: type(mag)
   Out[57]: int

   In [58]: mag -= np.mean(mag)

   In [59]: type(mag)
   Out[59]: numpy.float64
   ```
4. Finally, calling the `indicator` creation code will produce an array of empty dimensions and since you are trying to index into an array that has no size, it will give you an error.

Observe this reproducible error assuming that `mag` was calculated to be some value... say... 10 and `th = 1`:

```
In [60]: mag = 10

In [61]: mag -= np.mean(mag)

In [62]: mag.shape
Out[62]: ()

In [63]: th = 1

In [64]: above = np.where(mag >= th * np.std(mag))

In [65]: indicator = np.zeros(mag.shape)

In [66]: indicator
Out[66]: array(0.0)

In [67]: mag
Out[67]: 0.0

In [68]: indicator[above] = 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-adf9cff7610a> in <module>()
----> 1 indicator[above] = 1

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Therefore, the solution for you is to rethink how you are writing this function.  The MATLAB code assumes that `data` is a 2D matrix already, so they're computing the norm or length of each row independently.  Because we now know that the input is a pandas `DataFrame`, we can very easily apply `numpy` operations on it just like what is done in MATLAB.  Assuming that your columns are labelled `x`, `y` and `z` in your code and each column is a `numpy` array of values, just change the first line of code.

```
def segment_energy(data, th):
    mag = np.sqrt(np.sum(data.loc[:, ['x','y','z']]** 2.0, axis=1)) # Change
    mag = np.array(mag) # Convert to NumPy array
    mag -= np.mean(mag)

    above = np.where(mag >= th * np.std(mag))
    indicator = np.zeros(mag.shape)
    indicator[above] = 1
    plt.plot(mag)
    plt.plot(indicator * 1000, 'r')
    plt.show()
```

The first statement in the code is the actual NumPy translation of the code in MATLAB.  We use the `loc` method that's part of the pandas `DataFrame` to index the three columns you are looking for.  We also need to convert to a NumPy array for the rest of the calculations to work.

You can also use `numpy.linalg.norm`, but specify an **axis** which to operate on.  Since the data is 2D, specify `axis=1` to compute the row-wise norms of your matrix:

```
mag = np.linalg.norm(data.loc[:, ['x', 'y', 'z']], axis=1)
```

The above will coalesce the data into a NumPy array for you.

Comment: `data` is a pandas data frame that was read from a CSV file containing triaxial accelerometer data. The axes of the accelerometer data are `x`, `y`, and `z`. Thanks for your help. If you need anymore clarifications feel free to ask. The columns for the data frame are `timestamp`, `time skipped`, `x`, `y`, `z`, and `label` in that order.

Comment: @dirtysocks45 Understood. I've edited my answer to leverage the fact that you're using pandas.  I've made the code agnostic of the positions of the columns and used the labels directly.

Comment: That ended up fixing the problem. Thanks.

Comment: So why are we using `axis=1` as opposed to some other axis?

Comment: Because you want to find the norm of each row individually. That's why the axis is set to 1. If you set the axis to 0 it would find the norm of each column. The axis is important as you're determining what dimension is independent, which in your case is the rows.

Comment: If I want to return a matrix at the end, should I return `indicator`? Wouldn't that be an array though? Could I make the axes be a 2-tuple `axis=(0, 1)`?

Comment: I guess my question boils down to - is `indicator` already a matrix or is it an array?

Comment: It's an array whose length is defined as the number of rows in your data frame. Did that answer your question?

Comment: Also, axis being set to both 0 and 1 would return a single value, not a matrix. It would find the column wise norms then the norm of the result, which would be the norm of an array giving you one single number. This is the default option if you don't specify the axis parameter.

Comment: "Since the data is 2D" - is there a way to keep it two dimensional? I'm trying to pass this into another function that assumes I'm returning a matrix.

Comment: Yeah. You can add a singleton axis to the data, so do `return indicator[:, None]`.This forces the matrix to be 2D with a single column. If you want a single row, swap the order but omit the colon: `return indicator[None]`

Comment: It's not returning anything. It's plotting only but `indicator` would be a 1 column matrix so it would still be a 2D array. In MATLAB, all variables can be represented by at least a 2D array. A scalar is 1 x 1 for example. Numpy is different where a 1D array is really a 1D array. One thing that always gets MATLAB users when moving to numpy is the dimensions of the variables. Lots of gotchas when translating. Therefore if you want to respect the MATLAB code, make sure the array has a singleton column, so `return indicator[:, None]`.